# Search result returns more than expected objects in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of `Product` objects which have a property called `productName`. For example:

```
Product(
  ....
  productName: "Red Shirt",
)

Product(
  ....
  productName: "Yellow Scarf",
)

Product(
  ....
  productName: "Trousers",
)
```

What I want:

1. When some one searches for Red Scarf, I need to show both red pants
   and yellow scarf.

My current algorithm:

```
class Search {
  /*
    A hashmap is used to store the products.
    Key: productName
    Value: Product
  */
  final Map<String, Product> _map = Map.fromIterable(
    products,
    key: (product) => product.productName,
  );

  List<Product> search(String search) {
    List<String> searchWords = search.trim().toLowerCase().split(" ");
    List<Product> result = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < searchWords.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < products.length; j++) {
        if (products[j].productName!.toLowerCase().contains(searchWords[i])) {
          result.add(products[j]);
        }
      }
    }
    return result.toSet().toList();
  }
}
```

The issue with this algorithm is when I type in `Red S`, it shows trousers as well since it has `S` in it.

I need to solve this issue.

And what better algorithms can be used to reduce the time complexity?

**N.B:** The _map doesn't do anything. I just thought I might need it.

Comment: Add characters length condition, if search word contains >= 3 then apply it to search.

Comment: Why 3? I don't follow. Can you please explain?

Comment: 3 is optional, you can more or less than 3. But I think no/less different product have 3 first same character. If no char limitation, if you type `s` there is a lot of product have `s` character. But after you added 3 char limit, your code will search if user type `sca`. And just closer product name will appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most optimised way would be to use `RegExp`, the following code will consider that one of your words must start with one of "search word", for example with `Red S` it will search for any words starting with `red` or `s`:

```dart
class Search {
  Set<Product> search(String search) {
    final searchWords = search.trim().split(" ");
    final searchWordsRegExp = searchWords.formatToWordsRegExp();
    return products.where((product) {
      return product.productName.contains(searchWordsRegExp);
    }).toSet();
  }
}

extension FormatToWordsRegExpExtension on Iterable<String> {
  RegExp formatToWordsRegExp({bool caseSensitive = false}) {
    final buffer = StringBuffer();
    for (final word in this) {
      buffer.write(r'^' + word + r'|\b' + word);
    }
    return RegExp(buffer.toString(), caseSensitive: caseSensitive);
  }
}
```

### Use case

```dart
void main() {
  final search = Search();
  final words = ['Red S', 'red s', 'red', 'yellow', 'tro'];
  for (final w in words) {
    print('Search for "$w"');
    search.search(w).showData();
    print('--------------------');
  }
}
```

### Output

```sh
Search for "Red S"
Red Shirt
Yellow Scarf
--------------------
Search for "red s"
Red Shirt
Yellow Scarf
--------------------
Search for "red"
Red Shirt
--------------------
Search for "yellow"
Yellow Scarf
--------------------
Search for "tro"
Trousers
--------------------
```

[Try the example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=0a043e7e916dcbf79a48c73c2adcffca)